# Golang app in Docker exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

Tags: ubuntu, docker, go

I am trying to create the docker image of an app that was developed in Go. I have the binary called myapp, and if I execute it then it work correctly, I execute it with:

```
./myapp
```

Then, take that bin and put it alone in a directory called `mydirectory` and inside I put this dockerfile:

```
# iron/go is the alpine image with only ca-certificates added
FROM iron/go

WORKDIR /

# Now just add the binary
ADD myapp /

ENTRYPOINT ["./myapp"]
```

and then I create the docker image by typing:

```
docker build -t myDockerHubUser/myapp .
```

Then, when I run the image I get this message:

```
standard_init_linux.go:185: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

What does it mean? I found some post related with the same message but the thing is that my bnary is executed correctly without any problems

Answer (score 51):

You most likely either:

- use the binary for the wrong platform
- the binary is not statically linked (has not all the necessary libraries)

You can use `CGO_ENABLED=0` to build your binary statically.

Comment: I was running a go binary in an `alpine:latest` container, while the binary was built inside a `golang:1.11` container. Switching the base image for the building container into `golang:1.11-alpine` fixed this issue for me.

Comment: This ended up being my issue too (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71262223/why-does-switching-my-docker-base-image-from-distroless-to-alpine-cause-the-erro/71262352#71262352). I was using a multi stage build and didn't get both stages using Alpine-based. One was Debian-based and the other was Alpine-based. When they were in sync, it worked.

Comment: What does "wrong platform" refer to here? Is it like x86 vs. Arm, or something else? Is Alpine on x86 considered a completely different platform than Debian on x86, and there's something fundamentally different about the binaries besides the libraries they're expected to link to at runtime?

Comment: I was using ```scratch``` as my second base image in the multi stage build, and changed ```FROM scratch``` to ```FROM alpine:3``` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have to build the binary inside docker not in your machine.

```
FROM golang

ADD ./ /go/src/app

WORKDIR /go/src/app

RUN go get ./

RUN go build

CMD app
```

Comment: Do note that this produces a *much* bigger image than if you add a statically compiled binary to a small (if not empty) base image.

Comment: @PeterYes you're right but disk space is cheapest resource in the server , this method makes deployment and further changes easier on the run.
you can fetch latest changes from git and rebuild the image instead of uploading a huge binary in every change.

Comment: It's not about disk space, it's about network traffic in my experience. Launching a 15MB image with one or two layers is orders of magnitude faster than a 300MB image with tens of layers.

Comment: Just use a multi-stage Dockerfile. You can push the last image.

Comment: This answer doesn't address OP's original issue. It's true that they can leverage multi stage builds and get benefits from that, but their issue right now is just about how t run a built binary. It isn't relevant how the binary is built.

Answer (score -3):

Inside the container /myfile doesn't have the permission for execution. You have to do a chmod +x /myfile inside the dockerfile. Just add following statement before ENTRYPOINT line.

> RUN chmod +x /myfile

Comment: No, the result was the same :S

Comment: Can you please also add complete path to Entrypoint along with chmod. Relative path might be conflicting. ENTRYPOINT ["/myapp"]