# Why does switching the base image in a multi-stage Docker build from distroless to alpine cause "exec user process caused: no such file or directory"?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, docker-multi-stage-build, distroless

I'm following the guide at https://docs.docker.com/language/golang/build-images/ to learn the best way to do a multistage Docker build for a Go application. I cloned the repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/olliefr/docker-gs-ping
```

And I ran the command near the bottom of the guide to build the image:

```
docker build -t docker-gs-ping:multistage -f Dockerfile.multistage .
```

I also ran my own command to run a temporary container from the image:

```
docker run --rm docker-gs-ping:multistage
```

This worked fine. I see the application's output in my terminal. However, I wanted to switch the second layer image from the Distroless image in the guide (`gcr.io/distroless/base-debian10`) to `alpine:3`. When I made that change, built a new image, and tried to run the new image using the same command from above, I got an error about the user not existing:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: unable to find user nonroot: no matching entries in passwd file.
```

That made sense to me. It sounds like the Distroless image has that user and the Alpine image doesn't. So I removed `USER nonroot:nonroot` from the Dockerfile. So at this point, the second half of my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
##
## Deploy
##

FROM alpine:3

WORKDIR /

COPY --from=build /docker-gs-ping /docker-gs-ping

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-gs-ping"]
```

Then I built a new image and tried to run the new image using the same command from above. This time, I got the following error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory
```

I'm having trouble troubleshooting this error. Why does switching my base image this way cause this error?

Answer (score 1):

My base images aren't in sync. The base image used in the stage used to build the binary needs to be Alpine too. If I switch the first line of that Dockerfile in the guide from `FROM golang:1.16 AS build` to `FROM golang:1.16-alpine AS build`, it works.